# Correct use of git update-index --assume-unchanged

Tags: git

I've got a config file, `site.conf`, that contains Production settings.

I do not want to track my local updates to it. So, here's what I do:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged site.conf
```

Now I update this with my local database settings, etc.

However, when I try and check out a different, local branch I get the following message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    site.conf
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are switching between branches that differ in their `site.conf` contents. Git will not apply the changes for you: you've been telling Git that your `site.conf` is unmodified, but Git detects the unexpected local modifications rather than silently overwriting them.

You can either make sure your `site.conf` is identical in both branches, or forcibly overwrite `site.conf` and reapply your local changes manually.

Comment: I checked out one branch, copied `site.conf` to my Desktop, checked out the other branch and then copied it there. However, I still get that warning.

Comment: @SnowCrash To be clear, when I say it's different between the branches, I *don't* mean the local copy, I mean the version that was actually committed to the branch. If you still get that message, it's because there's still a difference between the branches.

Comment: yeah, I suspected as much but thought it best to ask.